# Android Self Signed Certificate Is Not Working Admob Rewarded Ad

Tags: android, ssl, admob

I get this error when i try to load admob rewarded ad. banner and interrestrial ads are loading and displaying fine.

Precache exception                                                                                                  hi: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: **Trust anchor for certification path not found.**

full error:
https://pastebin.com/x46Ub1NV

Previously i didnt get this error but for some reason i started to have it for few days.
I am using self signed ssl certificate with below method and i am able to succesfully connect to my server through https

```
trustSelfSignedCertificate(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.domain))


fun trustSelfSignedCertificate(inStream: InputStream): HurlStack {
        if(Global.debug){
            return HurlStack()

        }
        val myHostnameVerifier: HostnameVerifier = object : HostnameVerifier {
            override fun verify(hostname: String?, session: SSLSession?): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        }
        try {
            // Use the .crt file obtained via this script: https://gist.github.com/ivanlmj/a6a93dd142fb623d01262303d5bd8074
            val cf: CertificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
            val ca: Certificate = cf.generateCertificate(inStream)
            inStream.close()
            val keyStoreType: String = KeyStore.getDefaultType()
            val ks: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType)
            ks.load(null, null)
            ks.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca)
            val tmf: TrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509")
            tmf.init(ks)
            val sslContext: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
            sslContext.init(null, tmf.trustManagers, null)
            val sslSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory

            setDefaultHostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier)

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)


            val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient =
                OkHttpClient.Builder().hostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier)
                    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory).build()

            // default settings for all sockets

            IO.setDefaultOkHttpWebSocketFactory(okHttpClient);
            IO.setDefaultOkHttpCallFactory(okHttpClient);
            SocketSingleton.opts.callFactory = okHttpClient
            SocketSingleton.opts.webSocketFactory = okHttpClient;
            SocketSingleton.opts.secure = true;

            return HurlStack(null, sslSocketFactory)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return HurlStack()

    }
```

Comment: Its possible that you hooked the self-signed certificate to all the hostnames which is why the ads aren't loaded. Try verifying the connection only when the hostname matches your server.

Comment: I had a similar issue!!  I was setting the default SSLContext which broke Admob Server side verification: SSLContext.setDefault(SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"));  Once I commented this out VOILA!

Comment: Well i dont have that line i guess.